# Diffie-Hellman key exchange over the network or any other key exchange

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, public-key-encryption, grpc

What is the correct approach to build an end to end encrypted service ?

My thought process -

1. Create public keys and private keys for a user, share the key using public key with the receiver in the handshake stage (when two users chat initiate the chat)
2. Once the keys are obtained by both the parties, I suppose the pycrypto library can be used to encrypt the Tx side message and same can be decrypt on the Rx side using the key shared in the first step.

My problem - how can I achieve the DH key exchange? Do we have libraries in python?

PS: The application is being built using gRPC,

Thanks

Comment: Your above architecture is susceptible to a man in the middle attack.

Comment: Can you please help explain in brief how, I need a key to be sent to the other client in a encrypted fashion. I thought, DH will help in sharing a key securely, ain't it?

Comment: This is why you should use TLS - designing your own protocol often ends up being insecure.  Yours is no exception.

Comment: DH in general vulnerable to MITM. I suggest you read up on key exchange algos and how they work.

Comment: Voting as too broad, this site is not a good starting point for designing a secure transport protocol.

Comment: Yeah, I realized soon after I posted to stackoverflow. I suppose this should have been on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ 
Sry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about not reinventing the wheel:

```
import socket
import ssl
s = socket.socket(...)
secure = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile="mykey", certfile="mycert")
```

openssl will set up an ssl session and do the negotiation.  You can then communicate over the secured socket.